# Como centralizar com f-string, preenchendo os espaços em branco nas laterais com outro caractere

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatação

Gostaria de centralizar uma string preenchendo os espaços laterais com algum caractere.

Por exemplo, hoje faço isso com a função built-in `center()`, assim como pode ser usado `ljust()`:

```py
name = " Titulo "
print(name.center(30, "="))
```

O resultado é esse:

```
=========== Titulo ===========
```

Como posso fazer a mesma coisa usando f-strings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), basta fazer:

```py
print(f'{name:=^30}')
```

A sintaxe é `{expressão:formato}` (a expressão a ser formatada, dois-pontos e o especificador de formato).

A expressão, neste caso, é a variável `name`, e o formato usa os seguintes campos descritos no link já indicado:

```
fill            ::=  <any character>
align           ::=  "<" | ">" | "=" | "^"
width           ::=  digit+
```

Neste caso, o `fill` é o  caractere usado para o preenchimento (caso nenhum seja especificado, usa-se o espaço, mas neste caso usamos o `=`). O `align` é a forma de alinhamento, então usamos `^` para centralizar, e o `width` é o tamanho (`30`).